# HTML Canvas drawing an image is not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have this angularJS application and I am generating an image from the canvas. I have everything else working, I can even draw images from SVGs that are in the html, but trying to pull an image from a relative URL is failing to display.
I know that the image is being loaded and that it has actually found the right image because of some console logging.

Here is my **options** object:

```
// Define our options
self.options = {
    team: null,
    itemsPerRow: 3,
    targets: {
        containerId: 'totals',
        svgContainerClassName: 'total-item',
        svgClassName: 'svg-document',
        svgTitleClassName: 'total-title'
    },
    itemPadding: {
        top: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 50
    },
    canvasPadding: {
        top: 300,
        right: 100,
        bottom: 200,
        left: 100
    },
    sizes: {
        first: 1100,
        all: 300
    },
    footer: {
        logo: '/assets/images/k-logo-orange-black.png'
    }
};
```

You can see the footer logo.
The function for displaying that is this:

```
// Private function to draw the footer
var drawFooter = function (canvas, ctx) {

    var y = canvas.height - 50;

    // Draw our image
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {

        console.log(img.width);
        console.log(img.height);
        console.log(canvas.width - self.options.canvasPadding.right - img.width);
        console.log(y - img.height);

        ctx.drawImage(img, canvas.width - self.options.canvasPadding.right - img.width, y - img.height);
    };
    img.src = self.options.footer.logo;
};
```

So, the console logs are outputting the dimensions of the image and the canvas locations are well within the bounds of my canvas, but the image just isn't showing.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you create a live example somewhere, jsfiddle or something?

Comment: Hard to do, but I will give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question could never have been answered. I was using promises to draw other images and then doing a **$q.all()** once they had been resolved. I didn't return anything with the drawFooter so the image has not drawn, so I just changed the function to this:

```
// Private function to draw the footer
var drawFooter = function (canvas, ctx) {

    // Create a deferred promise
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // Get our y location
    var y = canvas.height - 50;

    // Draw the copyright
    ctx.font = '20px lato-regular';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.textAlign = 'left';
    ctx.fillText(self.options.footer.copyright, self.options.canvasPadding.left, y);

    // Draw main text
    ctx.font = '60px lato-regular';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(self.options.footer.mainText, canvas.width / 2, y);

    // Create a new image
    var img = new Image();

    // When the image loads
    img.onload = function () {

        // Get our coordinates
        var imageWidth = img.width / 2,
            imageHeight = img.height / 2,
            imageX = canvas.width - self.options.canvasPadding.right - imageWidth,
            imageY = y - imageHeight;

        // Draw the image
        ctx.drawImage(img, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);

        // Resolve our promise
        deferred.resolve();
    };

    // Set the SRC to the logo
    img.src = self.options.footer.logo;

    // Return our promise
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

and then I made sure it was being added to my pormises array:

```
// Finally add our footer to our promises array
promises.push(drawFooter(canvas, ctx));
```

When I did that, it all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two things going on here. first, if you are placing this image inside an SVG element, in Javascript SVG elements are created using a different namespace, using commands such as (with a few exceptions):

```
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
svg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','xlink','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
```

see w3 docs [here](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/docs/UserManual.html)

Second, I do not see where you have given the x attribute its variable, which is necessary, found on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag), (which also reference w3 docs [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement))

Comment: I don’t see anything related to SVG creation in the question – the image used is a simple PNG.

Comment: In the options, the targets area mentions SVG containers, classes etc. I drew a conclusion there, so it is possible that it is unrelated-thanks for mentioning...I edited my post to mention this uncertainty

Comment: CBroe is right, this image is just a PNG. 
THe x value is set by canvas.width - self.options.canvasPadding.right - img.width

Comment: OK, sorry I couldn't help.